# Creating loop to output json_encode to have multi dimensional array from two different tables

Tags: php, arrays, json, loops, while-loop

I need to create a web service for my android app and output in json so far all get services I created working fine but now I am stuck with creating multidimensional array for my getOrders service. I am using array_push for my other services. Here is my codes I have no clue what to do with this now to make it work.

```
elseif($tag == 'getOrders'){
    $query = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM orders JOIN orderprod ON orders.OID = orderprod.OID WHERE orders.OrderBy = 'admin'");
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    $i = 0;
    header('Content-type: application/json');

    while($i < $count){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    // check if user is already existed
        // user is already existed - error response
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["orders"]["OID"] = $row["OID"];
        $response["orders"]["OrderNumber"] = $row["OrderNumber"];
        $response["orders"]["SID"] = $row["SID"];
        $response["orders"]["OrderBy"] = $row["OrderBy"];
        $response["orders"]["OrderNotes"] = $row["OrderNotes"];
        $response["orders"]["OrderLocation"] = $row["OrderLocation"];
        $response["orders"]["OrderDT"] = $row["OrderDT"];
        $response["orders"]["SyncDT"] = $row["SyncDT"];
        $response["orders"]["Discount"] = $row["Discount"];
        $response["orders"]["Status"] = $row["Status"];

        $OID = $row['OID'];
        $query2 = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM orders JOIN orderprod ON orders.OID = orderprod.OID WHERE orders.OID = '$OID'");
        $count2 = mysqli_num_rows($query2);
        $u = 0;
        while($u < $count2){
        $PID = mysqli_fetch_array($query2);
        $response1["orders"]["PID"] = $PID["PID"];
        $response1["orders"]["Qty"] = $PID["Qty"];
        array_push($return_arr, $response1);
        $u++;
        }
        array_push($return_arr, $response);
        $i++;
        }
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

This is my desired result

```
[{"tag":"getOrders","success":1,"error":0,"orders":{"OID":"2","OrderNumber":"2","SID":"2","OrderBy":"admin","OrderNotes":"none","OrderLocation":"123","OrderDT":"2014-04-27 11:02:03","SyncDT":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","Discount":"0","Status":"Completed","PID":[{"PID":"9","Qty":"1"},{"PID":"2","Qty":"1"}]}}]
```

Oh btw I am still a newbee to the awesomeness of php and this is my first project for json output so please be detailed in explanation :) thanks guys love you all, you are all so helpful.

RESOLVED WITH FOLLOWING

```
'elseif($tag == 'getOrders'){
    $user = $_GET['user'];
    $query = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM orders JOIN orderprod ON orders.OID = orderprod.OID WHERE orders.OrderBy = '$user'");
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    $i = 0;
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $POID = 0;      
    while($i < $count){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

    $OID = $row['OID'];

    if($OID != $POID){
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["orders"]["OID"] = $row["OID"];
        $response["orders"]["OrderNumber"] = $row["OrderNumber"];
        $response["orders"]["SID"] = $row["SID"];
        $response["orders"]["OrderBy"] = $row["OrderBy"];
        $response["orders"]["OrderNotes"] = $row["OrderNotes"];
        $response["orders"]["OrderLocation"] = $row["OrderLocation"];
        $response["orders"]["OrderDT"] = $row["OrderDT"];
        $response["orders"]["SyncDT"] = $row["SyncDT"];
        $response["orders"]["Discount"] = $row["Discount"];
        $response["orders"]["Status"] = $row["Status"];
        $response["orders"]["PID"] = array();

        $OID = $row['OID'];
        $query2 = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT b.*, c.* FROM orderprod b, products c WHERE b.PID = c.PID AND b.OID = '$OID'");
        $count2 = mysqli_num_rows($query2);

        $u = 0;
        while($u < $count2){
        $PID = mysqli_fetch_array($query2);
        $response1["ProdName"] = $PID["ProdName"];
        $response1["Qty"] = $PID["Qty"];
        array_push($response["orders"]["PID"], $response1);

        $POID = $PID['OID'];
        $u++;
        }
        array_push($return_arr, $response);
        }
        $i++;
        }   

    }'
```

Comment: what's your current result with this code?

Comment: Hi there, I have resolved it. here is my complete code:

Sorry it's not letting me post the codes here it's way too long. Let me try to put them at the end of my question.